# Black market premium data, all countries 1960-2010

Tags: data-request, economics

The "black market premium" is commonly used as a determinant of economic growth. Data for all countries between 1960 and 1999 is available from the Global Development Network Growth Database at NYU here:

http://www.nyudri.org/resources/global-development-network-growth-database/

Does anyone know if there is a source that provides this variable after 1999?

Alternatively, is there a credible source that provides data on unofficial/parallel exchange rates that has decent coverage?

Answer (score 1):

I currently using [Havoscope](http://www.havocscope.com/) to look the global prices of black market. I'm not saying this is a secure source but the terms applied at least in my country, matches with other national resources about the same topic.

You can always search the [United Nations Office on Drugs and Crime](http://www.unodc.org/unodc/en/data-and-analysis/index.html?ref=menuside) (UNDOC) database, which has lots of information about the financial movement of what is considered *illegal markets*. Now,if you look something more specific, I suggest to look in the country's statistic, specifically in the data provided by the government, regional blocks and NGOs. For example:

- The Government of India has some data [about the topic](https://data.gov.in/catalog/variety-wise-daily-market-prices-data-black-pepper#web_catalog_tabs_block_10) in their website; this is considering you're looking for national data.
- When you're looking more data about Africa and the black market, search on [Open Data for Africa](http://opendataforafrica.org/); this is considering you're looking for regional data.